# pdns4 (powerdns) - when create slave zone , SOA record does not get created automatically with default value

Tags: openstack, powerdns

When we create slave zone in Pdns4, Default SOA record does not get auto created.
Does it expects SOA record from the slave zone master?.

Since SOA record is not getting create, dig on zone is giving Refused error.

```
pdnsutil create-slave-zone example 81.125.215.115:53

Host:~# dig @81.125.215.115:53 example

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> @81.125.215.115 example
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 8652
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.           IN  A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 81.125.215.115#53(81.125.215.115)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 17 19:58:33 CET 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 3
```

I am getting status: REFUSED and no SOA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was with little less knowledge with DNS.
Problem is solved!

It ask SOA certificate from the masters of slave zone.
In my case it was not able to connect to master dns server.

After fixing the firewall, it was fixed!